# Add JSON Element To Multidimensional JSON Object PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, insert, array-push

I have a JSON object in a file called info.json that looks like this -->

```
[
    {
        "name": "level0",
        "items": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "item1",
                    "type": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "item2",
                    "type": "type2"
                }

            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Level1",
        "items":
            [
                {
                    "name": "item4",
                    "type": "type4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "item5",
                    "type": "type5"
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Level2",
        "items":
            [
                {
                    "name": "item6",
                    "type": "type6"
                }

            ]
    }
]
```

and a php script that looks like this -->

```
<?php

    $json_string = file_get_contents("info.json");
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    array_push($json[0]["items"], array("name" => "item3", "type" => "type3"));
?>
```

I'm trying to insert a third element in the first instance of "items" in this array, such that when I open the JSON file the new element will appear. What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the output you are getting with the above code?

Comment: what's your problem here???

Comment: the file itself is not changing, though the value of $json is.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Do a `var_dump` on `$json` and see the result.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I'm looking to update the text in the file that the JSON object is stored, not just the value of the array when the program is run.

Comment: @laroy is not [Sahan Serasinghe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621883/6521116) you are expecting for?

Comment: @KrisRoofe, no. The more I look into it, I think I need to use fwrite or something to change the actual file.

Comment: Then you should update your question.

Comment: @laroy then you just save it to your file with json_encode and file_put_contents.

Comment: @KrisRoofe that's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @KrisRoofe, please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have changed the `$json` array, you need to save it to your info.json file with this,

```
file_put_contents("info.json", json_encode($json));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. Output the `$json` variable and you will be able to see your desired result.

```
print(json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

I made a sample for you: https://eval.in/818486

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello laroy you have not right the new json encode string to the file so your code will look like this

```
<?php

$json_string = file_get_contents("info.json");
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
array_push($json[0]["items"], array("name" => "item3", "type" => "type3"));
$strNew = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents("info.json", $strNew);
```

?>

Now you can check the the info.json file.